# How display barcode camera inside widget like this photo and take the results in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, widget, barcode-scanner

I try to make barcode scanner in flutter and i want to know how make barcode camera always open when i read barcode
Like make bills or something like that
Which widget can i assign to it barcode scanner function
And save the results
[image]

Comment: Try using SizedBox Widget to constrain Barcode Scanning Camera Preview Area. Also, please share code for better understanding of your problem statement.

Comment: I don't have code i see that on YouTube without source code and i was thinking how preview camera inside widget without press on button